# Azure devops pipeline single quote and space in parameters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Dummy question may be but one thing that always confused me is the whether the space between `{{}}` should be there and also if the single quote should be there.

Are single quotes necessary?

```
'$(AzureConnectionName)'   VS $(AzureConnectionName)
```

Is the space required ?

```
'${{connectivity}}' VS  '${{ connectivity }}'
```

I know they are silly questions but could not find the answer.

Thanks

Comment: It would be far faster for you to try both and find out on your own than to ask a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are single quotes necessary?

If you use some special characters in your parameters, the output may be different. For example, here is my YAML configuration:

```
parameters:
- name: test
  default: test&
  type: string

steps:
- script: echo '${{ parameters.test }}' 
- script: echo ${{ parameters.test }}   
- pwsh: echo '${{ parameters.test }}'   
- pwsh: echo ${{ parameters.test }}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

So when you are dealing with special characters in parameters, please pay attention to the single quotes.

> Is the space required ?

No, the space is not required. '${{connectivity}}' and'${{ connectivity }}' are the same.